# counting the number of times that the sum of two dice appear

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I want to see the number of times that the sum of two rolling dice appear. I'm writing the following code to show me the sum with myArray:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time(0));

    int myArray[12];

    for (int i =1; i < 10; i++)
    {
    int die_1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    int die_2 = rand() % 6 + 1;

    myArray[(die_1 + die_2 - 2)]++;


    cout<<endl<<"die_1 "<<die_1<<" die_2 "<<die_2<<" the sum: "<<die_1+die_2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        cout<<endl<<myArray[i]<<" ";
}
```

but the code is returning weird results to me. Would appreciate any help to correct it.

Comment: Remember the values in the array `myArray` are not initialized to zero. They will contain whatever random data that was in memory on the stack.

Comment: `int myArray[12] ={ 0 };`

Comment: Also [don't use `rand()`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to initialize your array (10) because the results are [2-12] so 10 answers :

```
int myArray[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

PS: to see your results I think it's better like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    cout << "for res[" << i + 2 << "]:\t" << myArray[i] << endl;
```

Comment: yes, thanks. just i should be added to two since the minimum value starts from 2.

Answer (score 1):

Intialize myArray with 0

```
memset(myArray, 0, sizeof(myArray));
```

otherwise, garbage value will effect the result.